# Display multiple currencies prices in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, currency, cart

I am trying to display multiple currencies,

Like we will give price in USD at backend but it will convert in Bitcoin as main price then doller price then eur price here is code I am using....

```
function convertCurrency($amount, $from, $to){
    $data = file_get_contents("https://finance.google.com/finance/converter?a=$amount&from=$from&to=$to");
    preg_match("/<span class=bld>(.*)<\/span>/",$data, $converted);
    $converted = preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/", "", $converted[1]);
    return number_format(round($converted, 3),2);
}

add_filter( 'wc_price', 'my_custom_price_format', 10, 4 );
function my_custom_price_format( $formatted_price, $price, $args, $unformatted_price ) {
     $price_eur = convertCurrency($price, 'USD','EUR');
    $formatted_price_eur = "<br><span class='price-eur'> (&euro;$price_eur)</span>";
    $rate_source = 'CoinDesk';
    // The currency conversion custom calculation function
    $price_btc = $value = WCR_Bitcoin_Exchange_Rate::get( $price, 'USD', 'BTC', $rate_source );
    // the currency symbol for US dollars
   $currency_symbol = '<i class="fa fa-btc"></i> ';
    $price_btc = $currency_symbol.$price_btc; // adding currency symbol
    //Bitcoin formattd price
    $formatted_price_btc = "<br><span class='price-btc'> $price_btc</span>";
    // The USD formatted price
    $formatted_price = '<br>('.$formatted_price .')';
    // Return both formatted currencies
    return $formatted_price_btc . $formatted_price . $formatted_price_eur ;
}
```

But I am getting just dollar price as good but other are zero. When I echo $price it showing me double price see screenshot:

[image: double price]

Please let me know where are doing wrong..

*(For info: WCR_Bitcoin_Exchange_Rate::get() tested and works already)*

Answer (score 1):

As I can't get the Bitcoins rate with `WCR_Bitcoin_Exchange_Rate::get()` I have commented and add instead a manual rate.

There is 2 errors in your code. This hooked function only accept the 3 first arguments. The 4th doesn't exist.

Also there is this small error: `$price_btc = $value = WCR_Bitcoin_Exchange_Rate::get(… …);` where you can remove `= $value`.

I have tested your corrected code and it just works for me using this:

```
function convertCurrency($amount, $from, $to){
    $data = file_get_contents("https://finance.google.com/finance/converter?a=$amount&from=$from&to=$to");
    preg_match("/<span class=bld>(.*)<\/span>/",$data, $converted);
    $converted = preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/", "", $converted[1]);
    return number_format(round($converted, 3),2);
}

add_filter( 'wc_price', 'my_custom_price_format', 10, 3 );
function my_custom_price_format( $formatted_price, $price, $args ) {
    ## Euros
    $price_eur = convertCurrency($price, 'USD','EUR');
    $formatted_price_eur = "<br><span class='price-eur'> (&euro;$price_eur)</span>";

    ## Bitcoin
    $rate_source = 'CoinDesk';
    // The currency conversion custom calculation function
    $price_btc = $price/15000; // WCR_Bitcoin_Exchange_Rate::get( $price, 'USD', 'BTC', $rate_source );
    // the currency symbol for BTC
    $currency_symbol = '<i class="fa fa-btc"></i> ';
    $price_btc = $currency_symbol.$price_btc; // adding currency symbol
    //Bitcoin formattd price
    $formatted_price_btc = "<br><span class='price-btc'> $price_btc</span>";

    ## USD (formatted price)
    $formatted_price = '<br>('.$formatted_price .')';

    // Return the 3 formatted currencies
    return $formatted_price_btc . $formatted_price . $formatted_price_eur ;
}
```

I get the following in cart page for one product added to cart:

[image]

Comment: Sorry but at my side its not working, even i tried at another site and still same problem :(

Comment: @MohammadUmer For me with WooCommerce 3.2.5 on Storefront theme it works.

Comment: 1,599.001,599.00
So btc 0 and eur 0.85

Answer (score 0):

Okay here is i did and i got all set :)

```
function convertCurrency($amount, $from, $to){
    $data = file_get_contents("https://finance.google.com/finance/converter?a=$amount&from=$from&to=$to");
    preg_match("/<span class=bld>(.*)<\/span>/",$data, $converted);
    $converted = preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/", "", $converted[1]);
    return number_format(round($converted, 3),2);
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'my_custom_price_format', 10, 2 );
function my_custom_price_format( $price, $product) {

     $newprice = $product->price;
    ## Euros
    $price_eur = convertCurrency($newprice, 'USD','EUR');
    $formatted_price_eur = "<br><span class='price-eur'> (&euro;$price_eur)</span>";

    ## Bitcoin
    $rate_source = 'CoinDesk';
    // The currency conversion custom calculation function
     $price_btc = WCR_Bitcoin_Exchange_Rate::get( $newprice, 'USD', 'BTC', $rate_source );
    // the currency symbol for BTC
    $currency_symbol = '<i class="fa fa-btc"></i> ';
    $price_btc = $currency_symbol.$price_btc; // adding currency symbol
    //Bitcoin formattd price
    $formatted_price_btc = "<br><span class='price-btc'> $price_btc</span>";

    ## USD (formatted price)
    $formatted_price = '<br>('.$price .')';

    // Return the 3 formatted currencies
    return $formatted_price_btc . $formatted_price . $formatted_price_eur ;
}
```

I just changed the filter woocommerce_get_price_html and got fixed....